# Duplicate Word document / instance without saving

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I tried copying the whole formatted text (there are tables, too) with:

```
Dim Type As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRecoveryType

[...]

actDoc.Range().Copy()
newDoc.Range().PasteAndFormat(Type)
```

Some text isn't formatted correctly (margins) when pasted - so it's not helping at all.

---

A second method I found here: [Copy-Content-from-one-Word-Document-to-another-in-C-VB.NET](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.Doc/Spire.Doc-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Copy-Content-from-one-Word-Document-to-another-in-C-VB.NET.html)

```
Dim sourceDoc As New Document("source.docx")
Dim destinationDoc As New Document("target.docx")
For Each sec As Section In sourceDoc.Sections
    For Each obj As DocumentObject In sec.Body.ChildObjects
        destinationDoc.Sections(0).Body.ChildObjects.Add(obj.Clone())
    Next
Next
destinationDoc.SaveToFile("target.docx", FileFormat.Docx2010)
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("target.docx")
```

... but I get an error - **Body** is no member in **Sections**.

---

So - how can I duplicate an unsaved opened document or the instance itself? Or is there a way to c&p everything correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the OS's own file copying abilities to make the copy?

Comment: @macropod that should be an alternative with usage of **IPersistFile**. The original file shouldn't be saved at all but it should be possible to create copies and modify these instead (watermark e. g.). It's just a question whether it's possible or not...

Comment: The only way to copy the entire document is to SELECT the entire document then copy. This includes the last paragraph mark, which includes the last section, where the margins, etc. Are stored. You could try that...

Comment: Since you don't want to save anything, why not edit the original and throw away any edits (i.e. close without saving), or use the original as a template and throw away the new document created from it?

Comment: @CindyMeister
That's what I did - see my first description. I did it manually, too, btw. The margins ain't completely correct.

Comment: @macropod
The original document shouldn't be modified at all except for the content itself and how should I use it as template? It's just an unsaved opened new document with some text, formats, maybe tables etc.

Comment: No, what you show us does not SELECT(); before copying. But if it's not working then you have no choice than to get the missing settings using code and applying them in the new document... But if this document has never been saved, what code is setting the margins? Can't you refactor and simply re-use that?

Comment: Yeah - but selecting everything and c&p it manually is doing the same as the code. There is no code for setting margins - it's a template.
But I'd like to have a clone of my document (or of the word instance) instead of c&p the content.

Comment: Word is a COM end-user editing tool, not a "dev application" - there's no way to "clone" anything. Doc.Content.WordOpenXML can come relatively close, but it's not perfect. And you lose even more fidelity trying to write it to Doc.Content.InsertXML. Better result if you'd write to a new file, then open that, but apparently you don't want to save any files. So you have to read the settings you need and write them to a new document - even better, create a new document from the same template, then the settings are there.

Comment: @CindyMeister 
Well - cloning an instance is a normal thing... there should be a way creating a document out of an existing, unsaved, opened document. A memory based solution without directly using the hard drive. **The way it should be:**
Create new document, write shitty things in there, this document stays unsaved, "clone" the opened document, modify the clone (e.g. watermark), save the clone afterwards. Yeah - the alternative is saving the document without affecting the active document via `IPersistFile`. I'll try tomorrow to modify a new document from the same template, hm.

Comment: <The original document shouldn't be modified at all except for the content itself> So what is the problem with doing exactly that and discarding any unwanted changes? As for templates, that's a fairly basic Word feature, and you'd access one via Documents.Add instead of Documents.Open.

Comment: @macropod - well. It just shouldn't be modified - so it's not important whether we discard the changes or not.
These ain't my conditions but I asked not for alternatives (because I know them) ...

I'm using now my alternative - saving the document with `IPersistFile` so the original document stay unsaved.